# Collapse group in one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with trying to create a collapse group, that would be in one row. I have the following html:

```
<div class="panel-group row" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-3" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-3" id="panel2">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-3" id="panel3">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row panel">
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapsed in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
  </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapsed in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
  </div>
   <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapsed in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Which acts like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxehk7p/3/) . What I am expecting, is the collapse to always be displayed in one row. At the moment, I lost the ability to close other collapses when I open one. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

To be more precise, I want row to show only one collapse at the time. At this moment, it is not possible. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add collapse transition effect to tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438848/how-to-add-collapse-transition-effect-to-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are tabs. You should not use collapsing groups.
Have a look at [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). If you really wish to use collapsing groups then you could solve this with javascript. Cheers

Comment: Cool! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if I can append collapse transition to tab?

Comment: A follow up question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438848/how-to-add-collapse-transition-effect-to-tab